# Redirect outputs to different columns of the same file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, io-redirection, output

I have a series 5 of commands working on several files located in several sudirectories. Suppose I want to redirect the output of every command as a new column in the same file, how can I do that. Kindly help me.

For eg. in the series of commands below, I would like to redirect the output of command 1 into 1st column of pop.txt, the output of command 2 into the second column of pop.txt and the output of command 3 into the 3d column of pop.txt

**command 1**
sed -n -e '1,33p' myfile | awk  '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }' >> ../pop.txt

**command 2**
sed -n -e '34,40p' myfile | awk  '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }' >> ../pop.txt

**command 3**
sed -n -e '41,49p' myfile | awk  '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }' >> ../pop.txt

Kindly let me know if I am not clear.

Thank you

Comment: It would probably be simpler to have a single awk command that concatenates the partial sums on the fly (or saves the partial sums and concatenates them at the end)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver, can you please tell me how do I do that.

Comment: thanks @steeldriver, that worked very well. Just one more thing. I am redirecting the names of the subfolders as the first column and the results of the above commands as the column2 , column3 and column 4. And doing it by (***cwd=$(basename "`pwd`"***) followed by (***echo $cwd >> ../pop.txt***)  in a for loop as (*** for f in `ls -d ./*/` ***). How can I now get to print the folder names as the first column. Can you please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell supports process substitution, you could use the `paste` command as follows:

```
paste \
  <(sed -n -e '1,33p' myfile | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }') \
  <(sed -n -e '34,40p' myfile | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }') \
  <(sed -n -e '41,49p' myfile | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }') >> ../pop.txt
```

However processing the same file multiple times in this way is inefficient - you could instead use a single awk command like

```
awk '{sum+=$3} NR==33{s1=sum; sum=0} NR==40{s2=sum; sum=0} NR==49{print s1,s2,sum; exit}' >> ../pop.txt
```

---

(responding to follow-up question in comments) to add the PWD as the first column, you could do

```
awk -v cwd="$(basename "$PWD")" '
  {sum+=$3} NR==33{s1=sum; sum=0} NR==40{s2=sum; sum=0} NR==49{print cwd,s1,s2,sum; exit}
'
```

BTW avoid constructs like

```
for f in `ls -d ./*/`
```

for the reasons discussed here [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. In that case how do I loop into my subdirectories get to print the basename of pwd without using for loop. Kindly advise.

Comment: @Rag you can use `for f in ./*/; do ...`

Comment: thanks a lot @steeldriver. It worked. I am calling the file steeldriver.sh. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it.